# How to solve a revert commit conflict

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-revert

I am trying to learn how to use Git and GitHub. I've made a simple html file and I'm trying to revert some changes.

I am using GitHub windows application and the repository is here: https://github.com/ionutincau/Ceau

My last 2 commits are "Add 13 to list" and "Add Accounts to list". I want to revert the commit "Add 13 to list" but I get this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hi, this is my first version</p>
    <p>TODO List:</p>
    <p>- Pictures</p>
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <p>- 13</p>
    <p>- Accounts</p>
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 76f0f70... Add 13 to list
</body>

</html>
```

What I need to do? How is this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s a simple conflict. If you didn’t add the *accounts* line, Git would figure out that reverting 76f0f70 is simply removing the *13* line. But now it hits the *accounts* line and says: “Whoa, I don’t know how to revert the changes from 76f0f70. I have marked the problematic part in the file, can you help me by hand?”

So you open the file, remove the unwanted *13* line and all the markers inserted by Git:

```
<body>
    <p>Salutare aceasta este prima versiune</p>
    <p>TODO List:</p>
    <p>- Poze</p>
    <p>- Accounts</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you can mark the conflict solved by running `git add index.html` and committing. The history will now be:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit | head -n 3
02933f8 Revert "Add 13 to list"
d4b2377 Add Account
76f0f70 Add 13 to list
```

And the revert commit looks like this:

```
$ git show --oneline 02933f8
02933f8 Revert "Add 13 to list"
diff --git a/index.html b/index.html
index 9f99341..6bec1cf 100644
--- a/index.html
+++ b/index.html
@@ -9,8 +9,7 @@
        <p>Salutare aceasta este prima versiune</p>
        <p>TODO List:</p>
        <p>- Poze</p>
-       <p>- 13</p>
        <p>- Accounts</p>
 </body>
```

Of course, in this case it would be easier not to bother and simply delete the unwanted line without using `git revert`.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your commit history. To remove your commit "Add 13 to list" first of all you have to take your head to commit "Refactor".

```
git reset --hard 8816fb
git cherry-pick d4b2377
git push origin HEAD --force
```

The first command will take your head to "Refactor"

Second command will pick your "Add Accounts to list" to master

Finally you have to push --force because you reset the head.

If you have any question or if I misunderstand your question, let me know

Comment: That’s not reverting, though.

Comment: I thought he is asking for removing "Add 13 to list" commit.

Comment: Reverting a commit is different from removing it. Reverting does not change the existing history, it records a new commit that undoes the unwanted changes.

Comment: I want to revert a commit, not remove it

Comment: But I do not understand why it does this, it's a simple commit, it shouldn't go to conflict in first place

Answer (score 0):

If your changed lines in two commits is neighbor, there will be a revert conflict. But if your change lines like this:

```
<body>
    <p>Hi, this is my first version</p>
    <p>TODO List:</p>
    <p>- Pictures</p>
    <p>- 13</p>
    something
    <p>- Accounts</p>
</body>
```

you revert and no conflict.
There is the reason:
[Conflict while trying a revert in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388382/conflict-while-trying-a-revert-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you root cause:
"linefeed,new line, br"

first time you input 
`<p>- 13</p>` |(cursor is there)

the second time you input( `<p>- Accounts</p>`), git actually think you
remove `<p>- 13</p>` and add new `<p>- 13</p>`,so the second time you just commit this content:

```
<p>- 13</p>
<p>- Accounts</p>
```

when you revert first time commit，git will generate new commit “revert commit”
Conflict exist between second time commit and “revert commit”

solution A
Actually，for this scenario，there is no need use revert command；just remove it manual
solution B
follow zoul answer

[git revert: Why do I get conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275070/git-revert-why-do-i-get-conflicts)
[git revert: Why do I get conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275070/git-revert-why-do-i-get-conflicts)